# Trying to create a react all

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, web, frameworks

I'm start learning react. When I start a react app using command `npx create-react-app <app-name>` it's not setting up a my react app I also tried it with npm but it hadn't worked with it too.
Then then I thought that may be my internet speed is slow that's why it is taking that longer but after waiting half an hour I realize that internet speed is not the issue.
[Image for a more clear understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uycHA.jpg)

Comment: try this `npx create-react-app test`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
npx create-react-app@5 your-app-name
```